# Postgres Restore single table from full .backup file

Tags: postgresql

I try to restore only one table from the Postgres full backup file (`.backup`). Here is the command line:

```
 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_restore --host 'localhost' --port 5432 --schema="schema1" --table="table1" --username "postgres" --dbname "DB4TEST" --no-password --verbose "/path/to/fullDB.backup"
```

But I get this error:

> Segmentation fault(core dumped)

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Comment: a segmentation isn't your fault! You either have a corrupt pg_restore or related library or you have run into a bug.

Comment: How did you create that dump? Is the "Segmentation fault" the only message you see?

Comment: Is this a standard PostgreSQL installation? What operating system? Try to get a [stack trace](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Generating_a_stack_trace_of_a_PostgreSQL_backend) from the problem and post it! On Linux you could just `gdb /usr/lib/postgresql/9.4/bin/pg_restore`, then `run --host 'localhost' --port 5432 --schema="schema1" --table="table1" --username "postgres" --dbname "DB4TEST" --no-password --verbose "/path/to/fullDB.backup"` and then `bt`.

Comment: I would try to restore it on some other machine into some other pg database. Even virtual machine will do - this way you will at least see if dump file is corrupted or not.